# How to getID from araylist inside onclick that is in a loop for

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I know that maybe some people go to vote down my question, but I'm trying to find the solution and can't find anything.

I have an arrayList in a loop for that display programmatically some buttons. Inside the loop I have an onCheckedChanged method where I try to get the id of the elements that I have in the loop.

My question is, How can I get the id for every button that I'm displaying. If I try to do this:

```
 arrayList.get(i).getId();
```

I can't access to the variable i because is not final in the loop, and I can't put the final int i because I get an error in i++

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            final ToggleButton toogleBtn = new ToggleButton (ActivityNew.this);
            toogleBtn.setWidth(140);
            toogleBtn.setHeight(20);
            toogleBtn.setTextSize(12);

            toogleBtn.setText(arrayList.get(i).getName());


            toogleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        toggleEnabled(toogleBtn);
                        arrayList.get(i).getId();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivityNew.this, Long.toString(idCategory), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        toggleDissabled(toogleBtn);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: just store `final int id = arrayList.get(i).getId();` outside of the listener?

Comment: No, don't work. That I want is get every time that i press the toggleButton the id of this togglebutton. If I do this outside of the listener, I always get the last id of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just store `final int id = arrayList.get(i).getId();` outside of the listener?

Or make a temporary variable to hold `i`:

```
final int index = i;
```

Comment: You mean this:  final long id = arrayList.get(i).getId();
            toogleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        toggleEnabled(toogleBtn);

                        Toast.makeText(ActivityNew.this, Long.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        toggleDissabled(toogleBtn);
                    }
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            final ToggleButton toogleBtn = new ToggleButton (ActivityNew.this);
            toogleBtn.setWidth(140);
            toogleBtn.setHeight(20);
            toogleBtn.setTextSize(12);
            toogleBtn.setText(arrayList.get(i).getName());
            final long id = arrayList.get(i).getId();
            toogleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        toggleEnabled(toogleBtn);
                        id;
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivityNew.this, Long.toString(idCategory), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        toggleDissabled(toogleBtn);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access the array to get the button id, you have access to it directly.

```
toggleBtn.getId()
```

Did you try accessing it like this?